# I can't get the white bar on top of site away

Tags: html, css

On my website,  I have a background some sections and a header. The header and the background are moved ~70px away from top! 
My site: http://www.scrumplex.ga/

Comment: There is Position:fixed inline style. 'style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%;;"'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is div containing iframe just before header.
 which has inline-style `style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%;`

If you really need to set it to fix then add `top:0` in same style. like this.

```
style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%; top:0;
```

See if it works for you.!

**Update :**
[image: Image- screen shot]

Comment: Ok i just updated the files correctly. Now the header is not at the top

Comment: Plz check the updated answer.I have changed the color using debugger to see if it is on the top or not. I found no -issue.! Do point out if any.!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `<p class="p-white">` has a `21.333px` margin on the top and bottom.  Override that in your CSS, and that white area should go away:

```
p.p-white {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the added rule anywhere in your CSS

Comment: Oh ok. Maybe a problem with my ftp client?